# change date format with Fun in read.zoo

Tags: r, csv, for-loop, zoo

I try to use this code to read multiple CSV file with read.zoo but I have a problem. the direction is different so I used `file.path()`. The problem is that: Date.Time into original file has Date `format= "%m/%d %HH:%MM:%SS"` and I need to add `"%Y/"` before or inside `read.zoo()` function. How could I do this? I try to use sub function but I need an argument. which? Is it possible to bypass this problem?

```
library(zoo)
for(i in Dir1){
   filepath <- file.path(paste(i,".csv",sep=""))
   #f<-function(x) sub("([[:print:]]{15})$", "2005/\\1",x)
   dat<-read.zoo(filepath,header=TRUE,sep=",",
                 FUN = function(x) sub("([[:print:]]{15})$", "2005/\\1"))
   filenames <- substr(filepath,122,155)
   names <-substr(filenames,1,21)
   assign(names, dat)
}

   Some of my data:
   Date.time,Outdoor Dry Bulb [C],Outdoor Relative Humidity [%],Air Temperature [C],Surface Temperature [C]
   01/01  00:03:00,0.0,50.,23.,16.3588068633603
   01/01  00:06:00,0.0,50.,23.,16.1696661072302
   01/01  00:09:00,0.0,50.,23.,13.8864861630478 
   01/01  00:12:00,0.0,50.,23.,13.006618496734
   01/01  00:15:00,0.0,50.,23.,12.5542552024807 
   01/01  00:18:00,0.0,50.,23.,11.6201669301972
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to think of this from an R point of view and `paste()` the strings together rather than use a regular expression, which is overkill here. For example::

```
f <- function(x, format) {
    as.POSIXct(paste0("2005/", as.character(x)), format = format)
}
```

Then call as:

```
read.zoo(filepath, format = "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S", header=TRUE,
         sep=",", FUN = f)
```

### Explanation of `f()`

To explain `f()`, notice that `read.zoo()` will pass `FUN` the `index.column` column from the file read in. This will be a character vector or a factor (depending on the setting used) containing the data from your file. So we can coerce to character via `as.character(x)` (`x` is what we use to refer to the data from the `index.column`). Next we paste the string `"2005/"` on to the data from the `index.column` column of the file `x`. I use `paste0()` for this as we want to `paste(...., sep = "")` and this is a fast way of doing it.

The final stage is to convert the resulting character vector into an appropriate DateTime class for R. I use `as.POSIXct()` for this. `read.zoo()` ensures that the `format` argument is passed to `FUN` so we have it available for using our `f()`, and we pass that to the `format` argument of the `as.POSIXct()` function so that it understands the structure of the date-time information we are passing it.

### Example Usage

Here is an example:

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(Index = seq(Sys.time(), by = "2 hours", length = 50),
                  Data  = rnorm(50))
dat <- transform(dat, Index = strftime(Index, format = "%m/%d %H:%M:%S"))
head(dat)

> head(dat)
           Index       Data
1 10/17 12:53:35 -0.6264538
2 10/17 14:53:35  0.1836433
3 10/17 16:53:35 -0.8356286
4 10/17 18:53:35  1.5952808
5 10/17 20:53:35  0.3295078
6 10/17 22:53:35 -0.8204684

## write to file
write.csv(dat, file = "mydata.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

Ok now assume that `mydata.csv` is your data file, read it in using the `read.zoo()` function above and the user function `f`:

```
myzoo <- read.zoo("mydata.csv", format = "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S",
                  header = TRUE, sep = ",", FUN = f)
head(myzoo)
```

which gives:

```
> head(myzoo)
2005-10-17 12:53:35 2005-10-17 14:53:35 2005-10-17 16:53:35 2005-10-17 18:53:35 
         -0.6264538           0.1836433          -0.8356286           1.5952808 
2005-10-17 20:53:35 2005-10-17 22:53:35 
          0.3295078          -0.8204684
```

Comment: I have a problem with your solution: First I ave change format to "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S". one problem remain and appear a Warning message:
In zoo(rval3, ix) :
  some methods for “zoo” objects do not work if the index entries in ‘order.by’ are not unique

Comment: That means that time indexes are not unique. In other words you must have two or more rows with exactly the same time, to the second. Is this the case? Do you have sub-second information? If so you may need a different placeholder for the seconds, see `?strftime`. Re changing the format - I may have misunderstood your original data set up (hence why it is useful to show the/some of *data* in your question). I took you literally as meaning there was an actual `H` after the hour component, but I suspect you mean that the hour is two digits, which is covered by `%H` without the second `H`.

Comment: Above there are the original data of file.csv.Your idea is correct but I don't know I have this warning. Could you give me an explaination?

Comment: With %HH there are more problems: Error in read.zoo(filepath, format = "%Y/%m/%d %HH:%MM:%SS", header = TRUE,  : 
  index has 37920 bad entries at data rows: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16...

Comment: You mean you want me to read `?strptime` for you? Where you see `"%m/%d %H:%M:%S"` change it to `"%m/%d %H:%M:%OS"`. The issue that you told me the dates had seconds, *not* fractional seconds. The format string I used handles seconds, not fractional seconds. `%OS` should be able to handle that. The problem with zoo is that once you truncate the seconds, you have date times that are not unique.

Comment: Yes, I told you there would be problems with `format = "%Y/%m/%d %HH:%MM:%SS"` if you data didn't have literal `H`, `M` & `S` etc. *You* claimed the following format for the date times `format= "%m/%d %HH:%MM:%SS"` and I took you at your word. I think here you were actually trying to be helpful and it has caused confusion. Your date times are in `format= "%m/%d %H:%M:%OS"` - the extra H, M, S you included in the format string are not needed with your actual data.

Comment: Sorry for my confusion. I try all different format and I realized that noone work well, but now I understand that the problem could be an other. In my data the first day is repeated 20 time for achieve steady state condition. Is possible that zoo doesn't understand that serie. what you think about?

Comment: It is just a **warning** telling you that some zoo functions don't know what to do with date times that are unique, i.e. the timestamp is **exactly** the same. zoo understands the data just fine it is just wanring you that some of its functions can't handle it.